# Rubymine command + click shows Rails methods but Not ruby methods. is it possible to command + click Ruby methods in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

So I'll have something like...

MyClassname.find_by_name("email")

If I command + click find_by_name my rubymine tells me "method_missing" as it is not a RAILS method, It's a method in Ruby. So Is it possible to configure my Rubymine to navigate to BOTH rails and ruby methods?

Comment: Ruby code completion and source navigation is and always will be a best guess attempt because the "type" of an Object is only known at runtime and can change per call or context. Ruby is affectionately called a "duck typing" language meaning the concern is method definition over type. For instance where would you look for the definition of `obj.to_s`? Also note in ruby you can do awful things that are still syntactically and programmatically correct like `Integer = String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MyClassname::find_by_name` is Rails method, not pure Ruby method. But it is defined dynamically

And yes, this method is really missing :) This way it works

I think that it is worth mentioning this in more detail to make it clearer

Please look example in Ruby docs:

https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing

```
class Roman
  def roman_to_int(str)
    # ...
  end

  def method_missing(symbol, *args)
    str = symbol.id2name
    begin
      roman_to_int(str)
    rescue
      super(symbol, *args)
    end
  end
end

r = Roman.new
r.iv      #=> 4
r.xxiii   #=> 23
r.mm      #=> 2000
r.foo     #=> NoMethodError
```

You can define method `method_missing` in your class, catch error there and make what you want

In Rails these methods are defined metaprogrammatically

Please look in Rails source:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb

This module realized `method_missing` method as in Ruby docs

```
def method_missing(name, *arguments, &block)
  match = Method.match(self, name)

  if match && match.valid?
    match.define
    send(name, *arguments, &block)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

And dynamically defines methods

```
def define
  model.class_eval <<-CODE, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    def self.#{name}(#{signature})
      #{body}
    end
  CODE
end

private

def body
  "#{finder}(#{attributes_hash})"
end


def signature
  attribute_names.map { |name| "_#{name}" }.join(", ")
end
```

So you can use `find_by` as prefix and attribute name as suffix

```
MyClassname.find_by_id(3)
```

And even you can find record using few arguments

```
MyClassname.find_by_id_and_name(3, 'name')
```

And as using classic `find_by`, you can raise exception if record is not found using bang

```
MyClassname.find_by_id!(3)
```

But RubyMine is not so smart and it doesn't use Ruby interpreter to check presence of dynamic methods so that's why you just see `method_missing`

In my opinion, using the classic `find_by` method in code is more transparent and understandable than using a metaprogrammatical suffixes

Comment: So let me parse this down and say that your suggestion is to refactor "find_by_name" into "find_by :name" .... would that be correct?

Comment: Yes, you can use `find_by(name: 'name')` without rails magic

Comment: Werent the dynamic finders depreciated way back in Rails 4?

Comment: @max yes, strange situation with these methods but they still work in rails 6 w/o warnings and still present in rails 7 :)

Comment: @max no, this is one of the most common misconceptions I have seen since rails 4 was released; however the [release docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations) are clear that "all dynamic method except `find_by_...` and `find_by_..!`" we're deprecated.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks, I always just viewed the dynamic finders as *clever* code and avoided them.